# How to associate status value to label value in "listing" ui component (Magento 2.2)

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, status, listing

I am using an ui_component (listing) for a custom grid in magento 2.2.
I have a status colum with various value, see below:

[image]

Here is the column declaration in the "listing" component

```
 <column name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sync Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>                     
    </column>
```

How can I associate the integer value to text value.

0=> pending
1=> synced

I know how to do it in a classic grid but I can make it work with the "listing"

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually Created a Status.php file in the folder [MyModule]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column

With the following function :

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{

    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            switch ($item['status']) {
                case 3:
                    $class = 'critical';
                    $value = 'Sync. Exception';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $class = 'major';
                    $value = 'Sync. Error';
                    break;
                case 0:
                    $class = 'minor';
                    $value = 'Sync. Pending';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $class = 'notice';
                    $value = 'Sync. Success';
                    break;
            }
            $item['status'] = '<span class="grid-severity-' . $class . '">' . $value . '</span>';
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

So now I have a fancy column style using a built-in css class:

[image]